# vi .bash_profile function mkdircd

Tags: bash

```
# vi .bash_profile
function mkdircd () { mkdir -p "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\"";
}
```

I gave the above command in *.bash_profile* 
But when I am typing `mkdircd new_directory` into the terminal I am getting following error

```
mkdircd: command not found
```

Comment: I added your code to my `.bash_profile` and everything seems to be working. You may need to just reload your  `.bash_profile`. You can see my answer below on how to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to just reload your `.bash_profile`. Try this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Alternatively, you can save yourself a few keystrokes by typing this:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

The reason that you need to source the `.bash_profile` after you make changes to it is because the terminal window does not recognize these changes. You can also just open a new terminal window and your recent `.bash_profile` changes will be in effect in the new window.

If sourcing the `.bash_profile` still does not fix it, try changing your above code to this:

```
function mkdircd() { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$@"; }
```